# Could Someone Explain This Java Regex?

Tags: regex

Could Someone Explain what this Regex does?

```
?['\"](.*)['\"] ?
```

Comment: Regex explainer to the rescue: http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl

Comment: Also, the best and most comprehensive article on regular expressions ever: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 0):

Explaination :

1. ? and ? may be separators here as ? in beginning is a syntax error
2. ['\"] : matches ' or "
3. (.*) : captures anything except new line
4. ['\"] : matches ' or "

You can check it further on http://www.regextester.com/